# What type of digital watermark is this?

Tags: watermark

I uncovered by accident the following block of bytes while doing some troubleshooting in a file which shouldn't have existed. I don't know what this is and I don't know how it came to be but I do know that it's not random.

This pattern, is way too predictable to be anything other than something which was put in the file intentionally. I'm not sure if it's a digital watermark technique but I think it is, problem is, I have no idea what it is, my hope is that the community will have an answer.

```
HHHHHHHHHHHH,...    4848484848484848484848482c1f0813
H   .......H,.7.    4820202016161616050116482c063713
H   ."4"...E,.<.    4820202016223422050116452c073c13
H...AHGG"..H,.<.    480e0e1541484747220416482c0b3c13
H..9HG<(9..H,.:.    480e0e3948473c28390416482c0b3a09
H..FHB..F..H,.:.    481111464842180a460416482c0b3a03
H..CHH+.C..H,.:.    4817174348482b14430416482c0c3a04
H..&GHHD!..H-.@%    481b1b2647484844210116482d0d4025
H...#*$....H..A(    481c1c1c232a2417020104482e0c4128
H..........H/.@1    481c1c1c1c1c1c1c1c1c1c482f194031
HHHHHHHHHHHH>'3B    4848484848484848484848483e273342
```

This particular block of 11, 16 byte strides was found at offset 0x000026A9. What you see is the ASCII printable bytes or periods '.' if the byte is not printable, whitespace is whitespace.

## Edit

After reviewing Willemse's answer I just thought I'd check if it really just was a PNG file, which it wasn't but it was an icon. This is what I found, but there were multiple resolutions in the icon and I think this is the one that best represents the data above.

[image: Icon found in file]

It appears as if this file somehow ended up being a powerpoint icon. I have absolutely no idea how this happened and why this data somehow ended up in the server pipeline but it did. I don't know if Azure decided to go berserk and served up complete garbage but somehow this data found it's way into the most unlikely place. This is going to be a story I'll remember for a long time.

Comment: Could you post the hex byte values too?

Comment: It looks like a simple grayscale image definition, without any headers or anything. I will try if I can see something meaningful in a minute.

Comment: "a file which shouldn't have existed" - explain further? Have you been hacked and someone's left this as their calling card?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe you're just new to computers and didn't knew your way around when you found that file. It's pretty normal to have files in weird places when it comes to Microsoft products (and in redundant places). An example of this is a MS Office backup folder on the system drive's root.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I'm sorry too, you seem to be confused about something.  I don't think you have any idea of what actually occurred here but I'll be happy to explain the situation for you.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren where was this icon? In a dll/exe? In a system folder?

Comment: It came from a file that was download from a drop location in Windows Azure. Only encrypted XML files are actually written to that location. These files are put there by a specific tool that can't even produce image formats. I don't know how these files ended up there but I have a vague ideas about how it could have happened. It's a rather absurd situation... I'm mostly boggled about where something went wrong and how it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

This is what I get when I convert the bytes to a grayscale intensity. Not sure if this is anything meaningful, but definitely not random.

Comment: Maybe it's a PNG file (or part of a PNG file), there are some bytes that follow this block in the style of `PNG IHDR\r¨f IDAT...`

Comment: OMG, it is a PNG file! Hang, on I'm going to post the image, this is just absurd. Nothing offensive mind you.

Comment: That's absurd indeed! Nice you found out and a funny story!

Comment: I think this is just textized version (a.k.a. ASCII image) converted from an image by a image-to-text tool.